# What is CLS_ANDROID_SDK_DEVELOPER_TOKEN?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

What is CLS_ANDROID_SDK_DEVELOPER_TOKEN in io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AbstractSpiCall
class ?

```
public static final String CLS_ANDROID_SDK_DEVELOPER_TOKEN = "470fa2b4ae81cd56ecbcda9735803434cec591fa";
```

This class gets bundled with android apk after adding firebase Crashlytics. I followed the standard documentaion from firebase to enable Crashlytics. I could see CLS_ANDROID_SDK_DEVELOPER_TOKEN remains same for different firebase account for different app.

1. What is the significance of CLS_ANDROID_SDK_DEVELOPER_TOKEN ?
2. Why is it same across different firebase account ?

Answer (score 0):

Fabric/Firebaser here - This is an internal identifier that the Crashlytics SDK uses that's not account-specific, so it's the same across different accounts and apps.